# Clojure grouping by multiple keys

Tags: clojure

I'm having a problem when using group-by. Here is the code

```
(defn combine-by-coords
  [values]
  (let [grouped-by-x (group-by :x values)]
     (persistent!
     (reduce (fn [res x-val]
               (assoc! res x-val (group-by :y (x-val grouped-by-x))))
             (transient {})
             (keys grouped-by-x)))))
```

Where the values of the map are of the form

```
{:x 754, :y 56, :someKey "zxyf" ....} .
```

The purpose of the code would be to group maps with the same x and y values together. First I group the x values together by using the built in group-by function, which results in

```
{754 [{....}, {....}]}
```

After that I would group the array of the key 754 by their y value. However this is where I get an error. It doesn't seem to be possible to use the key 754. This is the error I receive:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I've also tried the (keyword name) function to make a key out of it but this doesn't work either.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem or perhaps knows a way to rewrite my code? In the end I would just need the maps with same x and y to be grouped together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use numbers like keywords. You have to use `get`.

```
user=> (5 {5 :x})
#<CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (REPL:1)>
user=> ({5 :x} 5)
:x
user=> (get {5 :x} 5)
:x
```

In your case: exchange `(x-val grouped-by-x)` with `(get grouped-by-x x-val)`.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense - I wondered why I couldn't figure out which call to group-by wasn't working...

Comment: To add to this: notice the error you got: `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`

It is telling you that you're trying to us an integer as a function. That means at some point, an integer is being called as a function: look for where that might happen: e.g. (5 {5 :x})) Keywords and Maps implement the clojure.lang.IFn interface; you can see that by using `(supers (class {}))` and `(supers (class :a))`, and see that integers do not: `(supers (class 1))`. Cool stuff, powerful tools.

Comment: Thank you for that extra explanation @IsaacHodes. I was wondering what  that `cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` error meant.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could get rid of the x-val (the key):

```
(defn combine-by-coords
  [values]
  (let [grouped-by-x (group-by :x values)]
     (persistent!
     (reduce (fn [res [x-key vals]]
               (assoc! res x-key (group-by :y vals)))
             (transient {})
             grouped-by-x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#(= (key %) 754)` instead of just 754 as the first argument to `group-by`.

The problem is that the first argument to group-by needs to be a function that returns true for the values you want to group by. Keywords can be used as functions so these work fine, but of course an integer isn't a function, so we need to write a function that does the comparison.

Note that this allows a lot of flexibility e.g.

```
Clojure> (group-by even? (range 10))
{true [0 2 4 6 8], false [1 3 5 7 9]}
```

UPDATE: It seems this isn't the issue with the code in question, but I though I'd leave this answer in case anyone has a similar problem.